# ReactJS - Fetch Route with Query Parameters

Tags: reactjs, node-fetch

I'm facing an issue with my ReactJS setup where I am trying to retrieve query parameters in my url to append to the URL route that is being called in my fetch function. Is there a package I should be using to be able to achieve this? `cheerio` a ReactJS related package? Any way to do this without using react router or redux? I'm using `node-fetch` to make the call to my routes.

E.g. below would be '`http://localhost:3000/api?start_date=2017-11-05&end_date=2017-11-21`'

```
class BlogFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {blogs: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log("API Fetch Data Below");
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ blogs: data.blog, user: data.user, csrf: data.csrfToken });
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BlogFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: There's some discussion of it + some options here: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for any third party library. Just use the `window.location` object:

```
window.location.search // => gives you query strings, starting with `?`
```